# Backbone. Pass argument from router to view/collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Having some trouble getting my data where i want it to.

In my Router i've a a function passing an ID like so:

```
    routes: {
        'deck/:id': 'getDeckId'
    },
    getDeckId: function(id) {
        this.loadView(new DeckView())
    },
    loadView: function(view) {
        this.view && (this.view.kill ? this.view.kill() : this.view.remove());
        this.view = view;
    }
```

In my collection i load a JSON file. To that URL, I want to add the ID that I pass in my router.

```
var DeckCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model: DeckModel,  
    url: "myUrl"+id, //the id i passing from my router
    parse: function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    initialize: function() {

    },
    return DeckCollection;
});
```

The view

```
var DeckView = Backbone.View.extend({
   //initialize etc
});
```

So when the view initialises, I want to load this JSON with the passed ID from the router.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass id to DeckView constructor.

```
routes: {
    'deck/:id': 'getDeckId'
},
getDeckId: function(id) {
    this.loadView(new DeckView({deckId: id}))
},
loadView: function(view) {
    this.view && (this.view.kill ? this.view.kill() : this.view.remove());
    this.view = view;
}
```

Create url function that will use id and your URL

```
var DeckCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    id: '',
    model: DeckModel,  
    url: function () {
        return 'myURL' + this.id;
    }
});
```

Set collection's id when view initializing

```
var DeckView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.decks = new DeckCollection();
        this.decks.id = options.id;
        this.decks.fetch();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Implemented your code, but the id seems to be undefined in the collection..

Comment: Sorry. My mistake! messed up the deckId and id. Tank you!

Comment: I have a question, how can I pass id here `getDeckId: function(id) `?? I am not getting this

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I know this is late, but perhaps someone else will find it useful. It's not explained quite as well as it should be perhaps. The ":id" in the key of the route is what gets passed as the parameter to the function specified in the value of the route for that key. So if example.com/deck/1 is your url then 1, because it's at the :id position is your id that gets passed to getDeckId. Hope this helps someone~